# Stop redirect from https to http

Tags: centos, ssl, https, redirection

I have enabled SSL on my Centos machine where the website is being hosted. But when I try to access the website `https://1.2.3.4` it gets redirected to `http://1.2.3.4`. How can I stop this behavior?

I have added the following in my vhost.conf file

```
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
    Require all granted
</Directory>
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
     ServerName example.com
     ServerAlias www.example.com
     ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
     DocumentRoot /var/www/html/example.com/public_html
     ErrorLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/error.log
     CustomLog /var/www/html/example.com/logs/access.log combined
<Directory /var/www/html/example.com/public_html>
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

I have also tried adding something similar in my ssl.conf file inside `<VirtualHost _default_:443>`. But it simply gets redirected to http. How can I stop it from redirecting from https to http.

I have a different machine where it works the way it should and it has the similar configuration like this machine.

Comment: Configuration looks correct.. Perhaps it's the website that is redirecting?

Comment: Is there a way to stop the website from redirecting? I have a magento installation on my machine.

Comment: I don't know magento, but my guess would be that it is configured with a public URL, and that is set to use the http address...

Comment: Also, check if there is any `.htaccess` file in the magento root folder.. Perhaps it is redirecting from that.

Comment: Something that confuses me is i have the same config files on a different machine where the Magento works with Https. When i am creating a new machine it doesn't work the same way like the old one.